# difference between div and span in simple language

Tags: css

I need to submit an assignment in my college. Can somebody please explain me in one or two lines, what is the difference between div and span as I am not very good at css.

Comment: So you want us to do your work for you? I never do this but, STFW!!

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered so many times on stackoverflow. Please do a little research before asking a question. Check any of the below links:

[What is the difference between <p>, <div> and <span> in HTML&XHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434706/what-is-the-difference-between-p-div-and-span-in-htmlxhtml)

[What is the difference between HTML tags <div> and <span>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)

[Difference between div and span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047939/difference-between-div-and-span)