# Inlining a HR element

Tags: html, css

I want to use hr in the middle of the same line.

sample:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">TEST <span style="float: right;" >A 200T</span></p><hr>
```

Result:

TEST A 200T

---

But I want it like this...

[image: iwantthis.]

I can't put `<hr>` on the same line like this image. I couldn't find enough resources on this subject.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16434706/what-is-the-difference-between-p-div-and-span-in-htmlxhtml

Answer (score 2):

[image]

> **useful documentations** 
>  `css grid layout`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout
>
>  `grid-template-columns` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns ,
>
>  `min-content`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content

```css
#container {
    /* for this project we are using css grid */
    display: grid;
    /* text: auto width (minumum width possible)
       hr: 1fr (max width possible)
       text: auto width (minumum width possible)
    */
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    /* margin between elements */
    gap: 1rem;
    /* centering */
    align-items: center;
}

#container hr {
    /* removing the bug of invisible hr */
    margin: 0;
    /* removing the bug of hr take all height (because of css grid) */
    height: min-content;
}
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <p>hello</p>
        <hr>
        <p>world</p>
    </div>
```